# ! I can't find file `['

Tags: minted, sourcecode

I am writing my thesis by using LaTeX and the toptesi package. I am mostly writing on my laptop, but sometimes I need to switch to my other PC. I encounter some problems here when generating the pdf document. The command used to produce the pdf document is

```
pdflatex -shell-escape tesi.tex
```

The compilation ends at this point when the error is displayed:

> ! I can't find
>   file `['.

Which is kind of meaningless to me. The line that seems to cause the error is the first one of this block which uses the minted package to provide source code in the document.

```
\begin{listing}[!ht]
\begin{minted}[tabsize=4]{json}
{
    "type": "Room",
    "isPattern": "false",
    "id": "Room1",
    "attributes": [
        {
            "name": "temperature",
            "type": "float",
            "value": "23"
        },
        {
            "name": "pressure",
            "type": "integer",
            "value": "720"
        }
    ]
}
\end{minted}
\caption{JSON structure for entity}
\end{listing}
```

On my laptop my thesis is compiled correctly, the installed packages are the same, so I don't really know what the problem could be.

EDIT:
After some more trying I reached a minimal example that can reproduce the error:

```
\documentclass[english,12pt]{toptesi}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{listing}[!ht]
\begin{minted}[tabsize=4]{json}
{
    "type": "Room"
}
\end{minted}
\caption{JSON structure for entity}
\end{listing}

\end{document}
```

The problem seems to be in the different version of the toptesi package. Both machines run ubuntu 14.04 and all packets were installed from the official repository. If I change the documentclass to something like article the pdf is successfully created and everything works fine.
Here is the full error, as requested:

```
! I can't find file `['.
\listing ...\par \begingroup \programma \input #1 
                                                  \endgroup 
l.8 \begin{listing}[
                    !ht]
(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit)
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you look in the log file for the version number of `minted`? I have `Package: minted 2015/09/09 v2.1 Yet another Pygments shim for LaTeX`

Comment: Sure, it is `Package: minted 2011/09/17 v1.7 Yet another Pygments shim for LaTeX`. I think on the laptop is the same since I installed everything from ubuntu 14.04 repository.

Comment: Please, check the other one. However, I get no error if I try TeX Live 2012 or 2013, that have `minted` version 1.7.

Comment: I checked and the version is the same. On the laptop it compiles, on the other machine it doesn't (the full thesis, but a minimal document having only that part compiles correctly).

Comment: Try adding `\listfiles` on the top of the file giving problems and compile on both machines, trying to get past the error (do it from a terminal window and hit return at the error messages). Then look at the end of the log file, after `**File List**` and check the differences.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and [here](http://pastebin.com/wYAgpKm9) is the diff result. Some versions seem different, I don't know if this could be the problem.

Comment: Please always try to provide a complete document that reproduces the error, the most common reason for getting the error that you show is going `\input[file]` instead of `\input{file}` in which the file name that input sees is just `[` this error could be in your document or in an old version of a package, but hard to say with the information shown.

Comment: I know, but it is hard because if I create a new document with only the part giving the error, the error disappears, so I don't really know what to do.

Comment: In the diff it is clear that the main class (`toptesi.cls`)  is different. It can be anything  --- impossible to debug if you can't reduce it to a simple MWE using only standard packages.  If the one working correctly is the new one (version 5.86f) probably it is  simply a bug. The best advice I can give is to contact the class' author(s).

Comment: @Pyrox Please add the full error message.

Comment: I edited the question with new info

Comment: Your class defined `listing` for a completely different purpose so you get a clash, it over-writes `minted` definition of that environment `/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/toptesi/topcoman.sty:\def\listing#1{\par\begingroup....`

Comment: @Pyrox Write to Claudio Beccari, the maintainer of `toptesi` and ask to add an option for disabling the redefinition of `\listing`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your class defines `listing` for an unrelated purpose. If you do not need that you can re-assert the `minted` version:

```
\documentclass[english,12pt]{toptesi}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{minted}
\let\IWANTTHISlisting=\listing

\begin{document}

\let\listing=\IWANTTHISlisting

\begin{listing}[!ht]
\begin{minted}[tabsize=4]{json}
{
    "type": "Room"
}
\end{minted}
\caption{JSON structure for entity}
\end{listing}

\end{document}
```